# Converting numbers in binary form and saving them

Tags: c++

I need to convert some decimal numbers in binary form and store the strings made of 1s and 0s as rows in a matrix, in C++.
Regarding the conversion, I found this simple solution:

```
std::string binary = std::bitset<8>(128).to_string();
```

Now, I could simple scan the string and convert each character into a 1 or a 0, filling a matrix's row.
Is there a way, a C++ function (or a combo of functions) that allows me to avoid the cost of scanning every bits string?

Thanks for help.

Comment: How hard would it be to extract the bits from your number directly?! It's just powers of two...

Comment: What's a "decimal number"? You mean a string in decimal representation?

Comment: Did I understand this correctly that you want to convert each char of a string to something *without* iterating each char in it?

Comment: Answers.
1. Given a number N, I need to store in a matrix, by rows, numbers in the interval [0, N-1]. So, scanning the bits in string costs O(2^n), repeating this for all the N strings costs O(N*2^N)

2. Yes, I mean in a decimal representation

3. Yes, I'd like to know whether there's a way to obtain such result with a cost lesser than the one needed to scan every single char

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to convert to a `std::string` first and then convert that to `1`/`0`, you can simply access the bits inside the `std::bitset` using `[]`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

using BitRow = std::bitset<8>;
using BitMatrix = std::vector<BitRow>;

void print(const BitMatrix& bm)
{
    for(const BitRow& row : bm)
    {
        for (std::size_t i=0; i < row.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << row[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    BitMatrix bitMatrix;
    bitMatrix.push_back(128);
    bitMatrix.push_back(64);

    print(bitMatrix);
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b1776aba88760a4)</kbd>

Comment: thanks for your help. I decided to store bit strings in a matrix row because I need to multiply such matrix by a vector of integers.
each multiplication of a row by the vector, allows to select and sum some specific elements in the vector itself. this is what I need to do. I planned to use an Eigen's matrix. is it possible to multiply a BitMatrix by a vector of integers?

Comment: @Bia `is it possible to multiply a BitMatrix by a vector of integers?`: see this simplified example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac71a31702d7276c